# Setting a field value to the same object with a Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, object

I have two fields.

`Cost_price__c` & `Previous_book_value__c`

Currently, I use a Trigger on my Asset object to create a bunch of other objects and related records. However, I need to map the field of `Previous_book_value__c` to the same as `Cost_price__c` to work with them both.

I can't use the `Previous_book_value__c` as a formula field, I need them both to remain as a Currency field.

My plan is to add a second Trigger Context variable to deal with the field **before** inserting as inserting afterwards won't work. I feel like it's simple and I'm over complicating the entire process.

Could I get some indication on where to get started please?

Many thanks

Code:

```
trigger CreateProjectfromAsset on Asset (before insert, after insert, after update) {

if(Trigger.isInsert){
    if(Trigger.isAfter){
        AssetCreationController.assetCreation(Trigger.new);
    }
    if(Trigger.isBefore){
      System.debug('Need to set the field value of Previous_book_value__c to be the same as Cost_price__c');
    }

    }

}

if(Trigger.isUpdate ){
    AssetCreationController.assetUpdate(Trigger.new);
}
```

}

Comment: You can still create a formula field with a return type as `Currency`. Looking at your requirements, it seems better to create the field as formula.

Comment: Honestly if you want the field to be writable, just use a `Worfklow Rule Field Update`.

Comment: @JayantDas Appreciate the help, can't use the field as a formula as I'll be manipulating it in the future!

Comment: @AdrianLarson Have done this, thanks. I must have been making it too difficult and too worried about hitting SOQL limits (I was running pretty close with an API connection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this logic in a `Workflow Rule Field Update`. Using an `Apex Trigger` for this functionality is overkill, and it's usually better to use declarative functionality over code where it will work.

Comment: That said, I'd avoid mixing Process Builder with any integrations. The error handling is no good.

Comment: Already encountered Process Builder issues - that caused me to think about doing it directly within Apex but a Workflow Rule seems to fit my requirements! Will add an edit on the original question for those in the future that think the same as me